# C# Convert IHtmlContent to a string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, razor, type-conversion

I'm still relatively new, so sorry in advance if I'm missing anything that's obvious.

So to sum up what I'm attempting to do.
Basically, using Asp.Net Core, I am trying to get some names of products saved in to an array, however when I try to do so I get an error saying I cannot implicitly convert to a string. This is the message in question:

`Cannot implicitly convert type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html.IHtmlContent to string`

And here is the line that brings up the error `@{ saveNames[0] = saveName; }`

`saveNames` being the array and `saveName` being the value I'm trying to assign.

But when I add the `.ToString()` method to the end of the `saveName` variable. It does fix the error, however the names of the products are all turned in to this message on the page `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.StringHtmlContent`.

Any ideas? Thank you to anyone who responds. : )

Comment: XY Problem. Step back and explain what saveName is, where it came from etc...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static string GetString(this IHtmlContent content)
        {
            if (content == null)
                return null;

            using var writer = new StringWriter();
            content.WriteTo(writer, HtmlEncoder.Default);
            return writer.ToString();
        }
```